# Render template having Jquery datatables in .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datatables, erb

I am currently working on a project where I am implementing several reports. The report filters are remotely submitted to my action and the return results are displayed in Datatable with searching,sorting and pagination.

I have a drg.js.erb file which is having code like this :

```
var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'drg_datatable',formats: [:html],locals: {result: @result})) %>";
$("#datatable-result").append(html);
```

The partial  _drg_datatable.html.erb is having datatable implemented like this. Below is my _drg_datatable.html.erb file :

```
<% if result %>
  <table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered display">
  <% case params[:view] %>
    <% when "ahfs" %>
      <%= datatable_ahfs_result(result) %>
    <% when "drg_code"  %>
      <%= datatable_drg_result(result) %>
    <% when "inpharmics_id"  %>
      <%= datatable_inpharmics_id_result(result) %>
    <% when "provider"  %>
        <%= datatable_provider_result(result) %>
    <% else %>

   <%  end %>
  </table>  
<% end %>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I render the partial _drg_datatable.html.erb using .js.erb file it creates the table but escapes the javascript to add sorting,pagination and other cool features we get in Jquery Datatables. Can someone point me how should I go about doing this ? I have tried to render the partial is .js.erb without writing escape_javascript but then the partial does not get rendered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@grotori: Your solution gave me a hint of fixing it. I renamed my datatable id with a name which was not used in the application anywhere. I removed the initial implementation of the datatable in the partial and modified the code to render the partial first and than apply datatable to it. Here is what I did :

```
var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'drg_datatable',formats: [:html],locals: {result: @result})) %>";
$("#datatable-result").html(html);

jQuery(function() {
    $("#drg-results").dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span4'l><'span7 pull-right'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span4'i><'span7 pull-right'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true
     });
});
```

Hope this helps other trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly call the datatable js function in your drg.js.erb in order to "datatablize" your table. Ex:

```
var html = "<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'drg_datatable',formats: [:html],locals: {result: @result})) %>";
$("#datatable-result").append(html);
$('#results').dataTable();
```

I suppose you have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a selector of yours').dataTable();
});
```

somewhere in your application's javascripts. This runs once, after document load and applies to elements existent to your dom. Since now you are adding a new table you have to "re assign" the datatable behavior...